How to run net framework docker image on windows container using HTTPS
I have ASP .NET framework application, made into a docker image using Dockerfile, but when running, it only runs as HTTP on port 80 (default). How do I "add" HTTPS support?
Ideally, I want it to be optional and added as part of the docker run command, like it is for NET Core.
My dockerfile:
EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443

#BUILD
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/framework/sdk:4.8 AS build

WORKDIR /app

# copy csproj and restore as distinct layers
COPY *.sln .
COPY ["_Website Application/*.vbproj", "./_Website Application/"]
COPY ["_Website Application/*.config", "./_Website Application/"]
COPY NuGet.config .
RUN nuget restore -ConfigFile NuGet.config

# copy everything else and build app
COPY ["_Website Application/.", "./_Website Application/"]
COPY ["ExternalLibraries/.", "./ExternalLibraries/"]
WORKDIR "/app/_Website Application"
RUN msbuild /p:Configuration=Release -r:False

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/framework/aspnet:4.8 AS runtime

# Install IIS Rewrite Module
WORKDIR /install
ADD https://download.microsoft.com/download/1/2/8/128E2E22-C1B9-44A4-BE2A-5859ED1D4592/rewrite_amd64_en-US.msi rewrite_amd64_en-US.msi
RUN Write-Host 'Installing URL Rewrite' ; Start-Process msiexec.exe -ArgumentList '/i', 'rewrite_amd64_en-US.msi', '/quiet', '/norestart' -NoNewWindow -Wait;


WORKDIR /inetpub/wwwroot
COPY --from=build ["/app/_Website Application/.", "./"]



Are you using some kind of orchestrator, such as K8s? If so, I'd advise to use an ingress controller and take the certificate and HTTPS traffic off the container.

@ViniciusApolinario We are not, but if we would, we would want HTTPS throughout the connection stack and not terminate HTTPS at ingress service.

First, what kind of network are you running with Docker? If that's the default on Windows for Windows containers, you are running a NAT network, which maps ports from the hosts to the container. so you would have to use something like:
docker run -p 8080:80 -p 80801:443 containerimage:tag
In the example above I'm mapping port 8080 to 80 and 8081 to 443. I can then open https://localhost:8081 and access the HTTPS port of the container.

I am looking for a more complete answer, how do people add HTTPS to the net Framework web application before you even consider mapping the port. Do you create new IIS Bindings using PowerShell? Do you manually copy the cert across to the Windows cert store at "build" time? I struggle to find any concrete guide.

Ah, I see. Yes, IIS needs to be managed separately from the app. With .Net Core you have Kestrel, which uses the app config for that. With IIS, you need an additional binding for the port 443. If you were using a VM, you could simply point the IIS Manager UI to the instance. With Windows containers, you need a PowerShell line in your dockerfile. I believe this is what you are looking for: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/manage/powershell/powershell-snap-in-configuring-ssl-with-the-iis-powershell-snap-in

That's what I thought, but how would you bring your own cert (not self-signed) to the container for a real domain name? How could this be done as part of "docker run" command, and not at "docker build" time (dockerfile and compile every time a cert needs updating) and not configuring after the container is already running?

The best practice here, if you are not using an ingress controller on Kubernetes, is to have this done at build time. Think of Docker run as the execution of the application, not the moment of configuration. Ideally, you should configure the dockerfile to copy the cert file and use PowerShell to import it. That image can be rebuilt any time you need an updated cert.

Thanks, it feels a bit wrong, I think a better approach would be to volume mount a cert like for .NET (Core) part of "docker run" command, so that IT department could renew certificates more easily, without anyone needing to re-compile new docker image and making images deprecated. Thanks for confirming that this is how you would do too (as I feared). For this reason, we are not pursuing a containerised net framework app. Maybe someone else in the future will post an answer on how to do this in NET Core fashion.

Actually, after responding to your question I investigated this a little bit. The .Net team did investigate a more elegant solution for SSL/Cert management for Windows containers and IIS - they didn't find a good solution, but we never explored a native solution in IIS: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/get-started/whats-new-in-iis-8/iis-80-centralized-ssl-certificate-support-ssl-scalability-and-manageability This solution is what you are looking for. You can set up a SMB share (or a volume) as the location for storing certs. I have a blog post planned for this soon.

Here's the PowerShell implementation of this so you can use it in your dockerfile: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/iisadministration/enable-iiscentralcertprovider?view=windowsserver2022-ps your Ops/IT team can set up a File Share (SMB) and you can use that as the location for the cert and pass that into the IIS config in the image build.
